# How to sync requests after deploying WebHook with your own server

Tags: google-smart-home

How to sync requests after deploying WebHook with your own server

Answer (score 0):

You will need to enable the Homegraph API, create a service account key, and then call the API. Detailed instructions for each step, along with example API calls are shown in the [developer docs](https://developers.google.com/assistant/smarthome/develop/request-sync#node.js).